# HttpClientParams timeout

Tags: servlets

how I can Use HttpClientParams  to set timout time ?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for can be set using

```
setMaxInactiveInterval(int)
```

Here's a link to the [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setMaxInactiveInterval(int)) relating to it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use timeout with both versions of HttpClient

Version 3.1

`// create a singular HttpClient object
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
// establish a connection within 5 seconds
client.getHttpConnectionManager().getParams().setConnectionTimeout(5000);`

Version 4.1.1

`// create a singular HttpClient object
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
// get the params for the client
HttpParams params = client.getParams(); 
// establish a connection within 5 seconds
params.setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, 5000);`